3 axis load cell geometry
As far as I'm aware, there are two main types of  3 axis load cells.
The first type is simply similar to joining 3 single axis cells by their ends, each pointing in a different axis, like so:

(Source)
But there's another common geometry that is a bit more intricate and seems to be a single axis cell acting as a z-axis cell bolted to a combined XY cell, like so:

(Source)
I have no idea how the latter works. Both are also showcased in this video. Could somebody explain the geometry, where the strain gauges are placed and how it works? Or maybe point in the right direction for documentation/where to learn about this? The first geometry is pretty straightforward but the second one is more elusive. Thanks!

[Edit] and add link to datasheet, please.

Hi! I'm not sure what you mean. They are pictures from aliexpress (https://aliexpress.com/item/1005007010216190.html and https://aliexpress.com/item/1005008145819534.html)

Any reputable manufacturer will supply datasheets / user manuals for their product and a reputable distributor will make these available. AliExpress doesn't. Documentation costs money and leaving it out and not providing customer support is one of the reasons why they appear to be a bargain. "No datasheet? No sale!"

Yeah, I was just showing the images for the geometry desings. https://youtu.be/Ycx4V0sEVjg?si=88rS5Qh6vhjRM4hv&t=347 this YouTube video also shows both. I was looking to know more about how the non-trivial one works in principle

Done, hope this helps
